How do I make variable aware of the output of gencache.EnsureModule?
workaround In the end I just copied the make_py output to my project and imported the entry-point class.
How do I make win32com.client.Dispatch(APPID) aware there is a gencached version?
Consider the following code and note that %TEMP%\gen_py\ is empty at this time(!). Also note the casing of version/Version.
import win32com.client as win32
xl_dyn = win32.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application') # returns <COMObject Excel.Application>
print("late binding :"+ xl_dyn.version)
xl_dis = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application') # returns <COMObject Excel.Application>
print("it depends :"+ xl_dis.version)
xl_ens = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application') # returns <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.etcetera>
print("early binding:"+ xl_ens.Version)

When I run the exact same code again, win32.Dispatch() will now automatically pick up the gen_py stuff (and fail because of the casing error in 'version' - that is a deliberate error on my part to tell the difference).
I sort of get that - it all relates to methods to do early and late binding.
My question: I want to consume another COM server, let's call it SomeLib (it is a third party product I have no control over it). I know for a fact that I can early bind to it because I do that in VB6 and C#. But I cannot use EnsureDispatch('Some.Lib'), that command errors complaining about running MakePy manually.
Using output from MakePy I wrote this:
win32.gencache.EnsureModule(CLSID, 0, 1, 0) # using the CLSID and version - it generates a <clsid>.py file in gen_py folder
mylib = win32.Dispatch(APPID) # using the correct APPID

The issue: unlike xl_dis picking up the gen_py stuff automatically after it has been generated, my mylib doesn't. It is all there in %temp%\gen_py\ but mylib always remains a COMObject somelib.
How do I make mylib aware of the gen_py stuff?
